# How do i correctly call API with ajax in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I have a cordova weather app where I call an API which returns a JSON file with weather data. But every time i call the API with ajax it returns 404, but if i copy the same url in the browser it works.

Here's the part of the code where i call the API(the url is set before):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data, status) { 
        console.log(data.status);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hi urbic -- you're calling a HTTP GET so you don't need the `data` block. Also the `dataType` should be `json` not `jsonp` if the API is returning JSON to you.

Comment: @mrblewog i still get 404 even with your solution. I also tried with Postman app, and it works but with cordova app it doesn't. Here's the url that the app calls: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=b3a1cd2134e9f28c43beacab95ea8a1a

Comment: Are you including `https://` in the url? or just `api...` as you have here? Try `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=b3a1cd2134e9f28c43beacab95ea8a1a`  -- beyond that, I can't help you any longer.

Comment: It works now, i can't believe i missed that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries -- I've turned this into an actual answer now that it works for you, so would you mind accepting it? Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

Are you including https:// in the url? or just api... as you have here?

Try https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=b3a1cd2134e9f28c43beacab95ea8a1a

Cordova or jQuery may or may not prepend http:// or https:// to scheme-free URLS